# Which one is the correct one?

Tags: grammar

- (*1*) Is your mobile number 12345?
- (*2*) Is it your mobile number 12345?

Which one is the correct one or both are incorrect?

Comment: Please [read these guidelines](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/9902/2085) if you need help understanding why we close all simplistic “Is this correct?” questions and multiple-choice “Which one is correct?” questions as being off-topic proofreading requests. They have no depth, show no research, draw low-quality one-bit answers, and will never help anyone else. If you can edit your question to address those concerns, it can be nominated for re-opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic structure of an English sentence is

Subject + Verb + Object

Since "your mobile number"is already the Subject of the sentence, the subject "it" is omitted. In other words, the first sentence is right.